# Backbone js: register view events on parent element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I'd like to register view events on the view parent element. I tried the parent selector:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'mousemove :parent': 'mousemove'
  },
  // ...
});
```

But it is not working. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Backbone uses jQuery event delegate, so you can't delegate events to the parent node.

see in Backbone source code line 954, the View.delegateEvents function.